# CRUD processes using SSIS and C# into CRM 2011

Tags: c#, web-services, ssis, timeout, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to insert/update contact records in to CRM 2011 (On premise RO15) using CRM web services. I am using SSIS package to get data from my source and using C# (script component) inserting them in to CRM.

Originally I was using one row at a time using ContactInput_ProcessInputRow(ContactInputBuffer Row) method. This would insert one row at a time and after reading [this](http://fczaja.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/ssis-integration-with-dynamics-crm.html) post I changed in to bulk import using ContactInput_ProcessInput(ContactInputBuffer Buffer) method.

This appears to fix the problem at first when it starts inserting rows. But after about 1500 rows, I get timeout error. Normally, I would change the client side timeout settings in config file but because this is done through script component, I don't see config file. I have also increased timeout limit on server side to 24 hours.

The C# code I am using is same as the bulk insert code from the post (linked) above. I have changed the buffer size to 10 as that is what Scribe use and works well with CRM 2011 setup we have.

How do I fix this timeout issue? I am expecting to have around 5K records per integration.

Comment: Is the timeout error from SSIS or from .Net/WCF?

Comment: So does changing the buffer size still cause time out issues?

Comment: Hi Daryl, Yes changing the buffer size prolonged the session time but i was still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies. I think I have fix this issue by adding following block of code in app.config file (in script component).

```
    <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="12000"/>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="longTimeoutBinding"
              receiveTimeout="02:00:00" sendTimeout="02:00:00" closeTimeout="02:00:00" openTimeout="02:00:00">
                <security mode="None"/>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service name="longTimeoutService"
          behaviorConfiguration="longTimeoutBehavior">
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/longtimeout/"
              binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="longTimeoutBinding" />
        </service>
        </services>
        </system.serviceModel>
```

I did few follow up tests and I managed to insert/update around 7K records with no error. I hope this help any lost soul like me!